Mineflayer importing issue for non CommonJS
In a different script where I use CommonJS it works fine if I use this to import goals from mineflayer pathfinder
const { Movements, goals } = require('mineflayer-pathfinder');

however in a different script where it is not using commonjs and I use this
import { goals, Movements } from 'mineflayer-pathfinder';


error
it gives me this, it should work fine idk why it doesnt work
I've tried looking at projects like this:
https://github.com/TestaDiMucca/kraftizen/blob/main/src/utils/actions/behaviors.ts
but somehow theirs work and mine doesnt
also, I can import stuff like Movement and pathfinder from mineflayer pathfinder, just not goals for whatever reason
